# How do I restrict type of React children to be a span element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

My current component looks like the following:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
   children: HTMLSpanElement
}

...

export default function MyComponent({children}: MyComponentProps){
   ...
   return (
      <div>
         {children}
      </div>
   )
}
```

I want my children to **only** allow a span, no other element.

Problem is, I get an error underneath `{children}` telling me that `Type HTMLSpanElement is not assignable to ReactNode`

It seems this happens with any HTMLElement, giving the error `Type HTMLElement is not assignable to ReactNode`

I was curious if there's a way to properly handle such a scenario, or some other method of wanting to set up an instance where I type check to only pass span elements as the child node of a React element.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

interface MyComponentProps extends React.PropsWithChildren<HTMLSpanElement>  {
  hello: 'world' // if needed some extra props
};

export default function MyComponent({children}: MyComponentProps){

  return (
     <div>
        {children}
     </div>
  )
}
```

_or using `type` instead of `interface`

```
type MyComponentProps = React.PropsWithChildren<HTMLSpanElement> & {
  hello: 'world'
};
```